# How can I install git on my webserver with a curl.h no such file error

Tags: linux, git, curl, ssh

I have been trying to install Git on my web server. When i try "make install" i get the following errors which I cant seem to get past.

```
[root@site git-core-0.99.6]# make install
gcc -o http-pull.o -c -g -O2 -Wall '-DSHA1_HEADER=<openssl/sha.h>' http-pull.c 
http-pull.c:6:23: error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
http-pull.c:7:23: error: curl/easy.h: No such file or directory
http-pull.c:16: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â*â token 
http-pull.c: In function âfetch_indexâ:
http-pull.c:102: warning: implicit declaration of function âcurl_easy_setoptâ
```

There is alot more of that if you need to see it, but though part of it would cover the issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the curl development package, maybe if you install the source [available here](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) (or with the package manager of your distribution), it will work better.

For example, under debian, install `libcurl4-gnutls-dev`

Comment: I have curl installed from what I can see, but have just downloaded it and typed 'make'

Comment: @Ben : curl is not enough, you have to download the source code of curl to have the `curl/curl.h` header, see my edited answer

Comment: thanks cedric. My server says it is CentOS 5.7, but I dont see a lik for curl dev for that?

Comment: @Ben : then just download the sources, extract them and tell the compiler to look for includes in the curl source direcory

Comment: thanks for the assistance cedric. im sure you are correct but im a complete noob with linux/ssh etc so im not getting anywhere. Think i managed to download a centos 5.7 curl dev update but it says its missing other dependancies when i try to run rpm..